# Is it possible to add a column in mmssms.db?

Tags: android, database, sms

I have written code for receiving WAP push messages in mms application.

I am able to receive the WAP push message and stores that into sms table in mmssms.db.

The problem is while showing the wap push message in inbox.I am planning to give a separate icon for WAP push. There is no way to identify wap push message from normal sms. So i planning to add a separate column in sms which will be true only when it is a wap message. Is that possible to alter the sms table?

Am I going in the right direction? Please guide me.

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could create another database conatining the IDs of the SMS which are WAP push messages.
That could be a workaround if it is not possible to add a custom column to that table